# Problem in mouse configuration

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I have a strange problem with the mouse.

To set up the pointer speed to become slow.
But when I boot the Mint, it is an absurd speed, both the pointer and the scroll. To be the speed that I set up, I need to unplug the USB and reattach it.

I'm using Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon.

Comment: What type of mouse is it? Model/manufactuer.

Comment: Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would appear to be a known issue with this particular mouse. There's a launchpad issue titled:

- [Several Models of Microsoft Wireless and Wired Mice, i.e. models: Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500, Wireless Mouse 5000, Wireless Optical Desktop 3000, Comfort Mouse 4500, Wireless Mouse 1000 among others have erratic vertical scroll wheel issues in linux after dual booting in Microsoft Windows](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/971321)

which covers this issue. There is mention of userland software that you can use to reset the mouse when it starts misbehaving like this, vs. unplugging it and plugging it back in.

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/files/

There is also a download for the source and a binary build (DEB) available here via Launchpad:

- https://launchpad.net/resetmsmice/+download

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you! I believed that the problem was in the settings of Mint because Windows worked perfectly.